# Наследование классов в Python

Tags: android, python, python-3.x

В стандартной библиотеке Питона есть HTTP сервер. Есть желание реализовать его полный функционал на Android. На данный момент нужно решить проблемы с выполнением CGI-сценариев. Для этого нужно поработать с функцией `http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.run_cgi` (https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/http/server.py#l982)
Как правильно переопределить эту функцию через наследование класса `CGIHTTPRequestHandler`? 
Могу ли я написать так:

```
class MyNewClass(CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    def run_cgi(self):
        < новый код >
```

Смущает то, что сам класс `CGIHTTPRequestHandler` является наследованием класса `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`, но при этом не используется кострукций вроде `super().__init__()` или `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.__init__()` Да и вообще во всем коде сервера нет таких конструкций.

Answer (score 1):

Базовым классом для всех классов сервера является класс, определенный в модуле socketserver.

```
    def server_bind(self):
        """Override server_bind to store the server name."""
        socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
```

Переопределение метода должно работать.